# What is the right way to define buffer, pass to a function for a dynamic load?

Tags: c, buffer

please look at my code below. I was wondering if this the proper way to pass the buffer to a function, fill it, and get it back as a return. Maybe there are some techniques, which I missed as some programmers fill in buffer with zeroes before adding data into it. Apart from that, please do let me know if I have some minor mistakes or issues. Thanks a lot!

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

void get_data(char *ptr, size_t len)
{
    char* temp = (char*)malloc(len * 1);
    char sample_data[] = "data";
    strcpy(temp, sample_data, sizeof(sample_data));
    memcpy_s(ptr, len, temp, len);
    free(temp);
}

int main(void) 
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    char* data = (char*)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * 1);

    status = get_data(data, BUFFER_SIZE);

    if(status != 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;        

    free(data);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know quite what is asked. The function `get_data` you show isn't called, but you call `fill_data` which isn't shown. The function is wrong - you overwrite the pointer returned by `malloc` (you can't copy a string with `=` in C except in a variable initialisation) and then try to `free` the pointer you trashed.

Comment: In main you call `fill_data()`, but you defined above a function `get_data()`. It is not a simple name change because the latter is a void, but in `main` its return value is assigned to the `status` variable. Please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `char* temp = (char*)malloc(len * 1);
    temp  = "fill_data_with_something";` is pointless. It's like writing `int x = 5; x =42;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be quite a few problems.

I guess `get_data` and `fill_data` are supposed to be the same function? (But then why is one a void while the other returns status?)

First of all, `malloc()` can fail and return `NULL`. Always check the return value of `malloc()` and ensure the allocation has not failed.

Second, in `get_data()`, you allocate some memory with `char* temp = (char*)malloc(len * 1);` and use `char *temp` to point to it. But then, you effectively throw away that memory and make `temp` point to the string `"fill_data_with_something"` instead. In this particular case, the memory allocation within `get_data()` was completely unnecessary. And the memory that was malloc'd is irrecoverably lost and becomes a memory leak!

Third, you copy 256 bytes from a buffer than contains only `"fill_data_with_something"` which is definitely smaller than 256. So you are reading beyond the end of the buffer. You should only copy `strlen(temp)` bytes.

Worst yet, you then try to `free()` a pointer that is not coming from `malloc()`. This invokes undefined behaviour.